# Generating nested lists from a list

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
data = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I would like to write a loop that will give me the following lists:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

That is, I want a total of five lists (one less than the length of the original list). However, I need the code to be flexible enough that no matter how long the list is, it outputs the first element, then the first two elements, and so on, as individual lists, until it reaches the length of the original list minus one.

How can I write code to do this? Is there anything more elegant than the obvious for loop?

Comment: Ok, and what's your question? What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: If one of these answers helped you, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list comprehension. Simple and easy.

```
In [652]: [list_[:i] for i in range(1, len(list_))]
Out[652]: [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

This is the slick equivalent of a `for` loop doing the same thing:

```
In [654]: output = []
     ...: for i in range(1, len(list_)):
     ...:     output.append(list_[:i]) 
     ...: print(output)
     ...: 
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a silly alternative for fun...

```
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([x] for x in data))[:-1]
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Ah, this is nice. I was scratching my head trying to figure out how to use `itertools.accumulate` here. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]

def one_by_one(l):
    previous = []
    total = len(l) - 1
    for i, element in enumerate(l):
        if i != total:
            previous.append(element)
            print previous

one_by_one(my_list)
```

Here I create a function, `one_by_one` , which iterates over the list it takes as its parameter. During iteration, it appends each list value to an empty list and prints what it has so far - only if the element is not the final one. The output is just what you wanted:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

This function just prints the output. If you would like to keep these lists for later use, then that would take a slightly different approach. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
for i,x in enumerate(list):
    print (list[:i])
```

Comment: Why `pass`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @bendl I always add pass at the end of an loop. Learned it that way i guess. Why not, whats wrong with it?

Comment: There's no reason at all for it to be there. The idea of python is not to write anything without purpose. Also it's confusing. `pass` should **only** be used when the code will not run without it. If it's there someone will come along later and think "Why won't this code work without a `pass` statement?"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Since I'm a newbie, should i now delete the `pass`? Because it makes these comments kind of useless

Comment: For the sake of keeping answers high quality, I'd say yes (not that I think it matters much on a post that will likely be deleted). People can check the edit history if they're confused by the comments.